# Converting object literals into functions in ES6 Javascript

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, functional-programming

I was reading [this article](https://hackernoon.com/rethinking-javascript-eliminate-the-switch-statement-for-better-code-5c81c044716d) at hackernoon.com that tries to explain a particular approach to turn javascript Switch/Case into a functional version of it self.

The article reaches a point where they set a function called `switchcase`, defined as:

```
const switchcase = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key] : defaultCase
```

They also say that this function has a problem, as "the entire object literal is evaluated before being passed to the switchcase function". And so they decide to convert the values in the object literal to functions. To do so they utilize this syntax:

```
const switchcaseF = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  switchcase(cases)(defaultCase)(key)()
```

My question is: How does this last syntax work? Can anyone break it down for me?

Comment: Are you talking about this line specifically? `switchcase(cases)(defaultCase)(key)()`

Comment: @silencedogood yes, I am.

Comment: `switchcase(cases)(defaultCase)(key)` - return `cases[key]` or `default`, and then just call it wit `()`

Comment: Wouldn't it just evaluate the entire object literal when running switchcase(cases)(defaultCase)(key) to return case[key] and then call it anyways?

Comment: what is the benefit fo duplicating `switchcase`?

Comment: Interesting question, but please never use such a thing in production. So hard to understand what is going on.

Comment: @NinaScholz What you mean by duplicating? Converting to functional approach or using swichcaseF?

Comment: sorry, i missed the functions instead of values of the handed over object.

Comment: but with this approach, you need a function for the default as well, because of the final call.

Comment: @NinaScholz Correct, later we should use an approach such as `const execIfFunction = fn => fn instanceof Function ? fn(): fn;` and then switchcaseF would look like: `cases => defaultFn => key => execIfFunction(switchOnBase(cases)(defaultFn)(key));`

Comment: Please don't do that. Encoding random conditional branches with made-up functions isn't beneficial at all but confusing and hard to follow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How does this last syntax work? Can anyone break it down for me?

Consider the definition of `switchcase` and `switchcaseF`.

```js
const switchcase = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key] : defaultCase

const switchcaseF = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  switchcase(cases)(defaultCase)(key)()
```

If we inline the application of `switchcase` within `switchaseF` we get the following.

```js
const switchcaseF = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  (cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key] : defaultCase)()
//|____________________________________________________|
//                           |
//          switchcase(cases)(defaultCase)(key)
```

Furthermore, we can move the function application inside the conditional expression.

```js
const switchcaseF = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key]() : defaultCase()
```

Now, consider the example from the [article](https://hackernoon.com/rethinking-javascript-eliminate-the-switch-statement-for-better-code-5c81c044716d) that you linked to.

```js
const counter = (state = 0, action) =>
  switchcaseF({
    'INCREMENT': () => state + 1,
    'DECREMENT': () => state - 1
  })(() => state)(action.type)
```

If we inline the application of `switchcaseF` within `counter` we get the following.

```js
const counter = (state = 0, action) => {
  const cases = {
    'INCREMENT': () => state + 1,
    'DECREMENT': () => state - 1
  }
  const defaultCase = () => state
  const key = action.type
  return cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key]() : defaultCase()
}
```

Hence, if `action.type` is `'INCREMENT'` then the result is `state + 1`. If `action.type` is `'DECREMENT'` then the result is `state - 1`. Otherwise, the result is `state`.

The reason we write expressions like `() => state + 1` instead of simply `state + 1` is for [lazy evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lazy_evaluation). We only evaluate the body of `() => state + 1` when the function is called. This prevents incorrect behaviour like in the following example.

```js
const switchcase = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key] : defaultCase

const never = () => { while (true); }

const example = key => switchcase({
  never: never()
})('it works')(key)

console.log(example('it should work')) // expected 'it works' but never returns
```

Using `switchcaseF` solves this problem.

```js
const switchcaseF = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key]() : defaultCase()

const never = () => { while (true); }

const example = key => switchcaseF({
  never: () => never()
})(() => 'it works')(key)

console.log(example('it should work')) // 'it works' as expected
```

However, note that you can use getters to make it work with `switchcase` too.

```js
const switchcase = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key] : defaultCase

const never = () => { while (true); }

const example = key => switchcase({
  get never() { return never(); }
})('it works')(key)

console.log(example('it should work')) // 'it works' as expected
```

We can also make `defaultCase` lazy.

```js
const switchcase2 = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key] : defaultCase.value

const never = () => { while (true); }

const example = key => switchcase2({
  get never() { return never(); }
})({ get value() { console.log('yes'); return 'it works'; } })(key)

console.log(example('it should work')) // 'yes' 'it works' as expected
```

If you don't want it to be lazy then you can wrap it in `strict` as follows.

```js
const switchcase2 = cases => defaultCase => key =>
  cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key] : defaultCase.value

const never = () => { while (true); }

const strict = value => ({ value })

const example = key => switchcase2({
  get never() { return never(); }
})(strict('it works'))(key)

console.log(example('it should work')) // 'it works' as expected
```

Hope that elucidates your doubts.

Answer (score 2):

By using functions, you need to take a function for `defaultCase` as well.

```js
const switchcase = cases => defaultCase => key =>
        cases.hasOwnProperty(key) ? cases[key] : defaultCase

const switchcaseF = cases => defaultCase => key =>
        switchcase(cases)(() => defaultCase)(key)()
//                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^      ^^
  
console.log(switchcaseF({ foo: () => 'bar' })('nothing')('foo'));
console.log(switchcaseF({ foo: () => 'bar' })('nothing')('baz'));
```

Comment: Actually, you don't. It's expected that `defaultCase` is a function. The type of `switchcase` is `Map String a -> a -> String -> a` and the type of `switchcaseF` is `Map String (Thunk a) -> Thunk a -> String -> a`. Hence, in your examples you'd write `switchcaseF({ foo: () => 'bar' })(() => 'nothing')('foo')` and `switchcaseF({ foo: () => 'bar' })(() => 'nothing')('baz')` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

It would be cleared if rewrite this with simple function.

First, rewrite `switchcase`. This function is a result of currying next function with three arguments

```
function switchcase(cases, defaultCase, key){
    if(cases.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        return cases[key];
    }
    return defaultCase;
}
```

So, if rewrite `switchcaseF` we get next:

```
function switchcaseF(cases, defaultCase, key){
    var selectedFunc = switchcase(cases, defaultCase, key);

    return selectedFunc();
}
```

Comment: You need to return the result of `selectedFunc`.

Comment: @AaditMShah, fixed